# Elixir Phoenix flash messages do not show up

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am trying to display flash messages in a Phoenix app, but they don't seem to show up. I have tried many different things, one of them is:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <%
    info = get_flash(@conn, :info)
    error = get_flash(@conn, :error)
    %>
    <% if info do %>
      <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert"><%= info %></div>
    <% end %>
    <% if error do %>
      <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><%= error %></div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone point me to the right code?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to use `<%=` instead of `<%`

```
<%= if info do %>
  <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert"><%= info %></div>
<% end %>
```

From [the docs](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/eex/EEx.html#summary):

> All expressions that output something to the template must use the equals sign (=). Since everything in Elixir is an expression, there are no exceptions for this rule. For example, while some template languages would special-case if clauses, they are treated the same in EEx and also require = in order to have their result printed:

Comment: The link for docs is outdated. Maybe this is the updated link https://hexdocs.pm/eex/EEx.html#tags